postgresql, how to trigger a trigger function when only inserting successfully?
I set up a trigger for copying some fields of a new record to a new table when a new record is inserted. Anyway, that can successfully run. but my target is triggering when inserting successfully or completely, but now the trigger will be conducted whenever it is successful or failed.
I tried to find the solving in search engining, but I still struggling on this. So I pursue the solving here, thanks guys.
supplement：
for example:
I reinsert the same record twice, but I set the "item" as the primary key, so the second time will not successfully insert. but the t2 still inserted by trigger.
trigger function:
Begin
INSERT INTO t2 (item,attr_1)
VALUES (New.item,New.attr_1);
RETURN New;
END;

This's the reproduction of issue:
postgres=# insert into t1 (item,attr_1,attr_2,attr_3) values ('a',1,2,3) on conflict(item)do nothing;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from t1;
 item | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3
------+--------+--------+--------
 a    |      1 |      2 |      3
(1 行记录)


postgres=# select * from t2;
 item | attr_1
------+--------
 a    |      1
(1 行记录)


postgres=# insert into t1 (item,attr_1,attr_2,attr_3) values ('a',1,2,3) on conflict(item)do nothing;
INSERT 0 0
postgres=# select * from t2;
 item | attr_1
------+--------
 a    |      1
 a    |      1
(2 行记录)

Results Picture

The SO community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images. Additionally clearly define what you mean by successfully or completely  what you mean by failed (typically when an insert fails it throws an exception and no trigger is executed.)

@Belayer, thanks for your suggestion, I add more information about the issue.

That should not happen, but without seeing the complete trigger function definition and the CREATE TRIGGER statement as well as the definition of both tables and any other triggers on them, we could only guess.

What is happening:
create table trg_test(id integer primary key, fld1 varchar);
create table trg_test2(id integer , fld1 varchar); 

CREATE FUNCTION cp_record( )
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Action is %', TG_OP;
    INSERT INTO trg_test2 VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.fld1);
    RETURN NEW;
END;

$function$
;
create trigger trg_test_cp_record before insert on trg_test for each row execute function cp_record();

insert into trg_test values (1, 'test') on conflict(id) do nothing;
NOTICE:  Action is INSERT
INSERT 0 1
insert into trg_test values (1, 'test2') on conflict(id) do nothing;
NOTICE:  Action is INSERT
INSERT 0 0
insert into trg_test values (1, 'test3') on conflict(id) do nothing;
NOTICE:  Action is INSERT
INSERT 0 0

select * from trg_test;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test

select * from trg_test2;
 id | fld1  
----+-------
  1 | test
  1 | test2
  1 | test3


INSERT ... ON CONFLICT tries the INSERT first and  trips the BEFORE INSERT trigger which runs the INSERT INTO trg_test2 VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.fld1); statement. When there is no conflict then the INSERT proceeds on the original table and you get INSERT 0 1. When the CONFLICT occurs  the original INSERT does not happen, hence INSERT 0 0.  The INSERT inside the trigger does happen though and it shows up in the other table.
If you change the trigger to AFTER INSERT:
create trigger trg_test_cp_record after insert on trg_test for each row execute function cp_record();

Then:
insert into trg_test values (1, 'test') on conflict(id) do nothing;
NOTICE:  Action is INSERT
INSERT 0 1
insert into trg_test values (1, 'test2') on conflict(id) do nothing;
INSERT 0 0
insert into trg_test values (1, 'test3') on conflict(id) do nothing;
INSERT 0 0

select * from trg_test;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test
(1 row)

select * from trg_test;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test
(1 row)

test=# select * from trg_test2;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test


The original un-conflicted statement passes through as an INSERT. The conflict statements do not as the on conflict clause kicks in and the INSERT does not reach the AFTER trigger.

Gosh, That is the problem I met! Thank you so much for your clarity explanation and patience, even though I didn't present it enough.
